# Categorical Variable in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have imported a some data from CSV into R and would like to convert multiple columns from "text" to categorical variables. For example, if I have the below mentioned columns:

```
Product

Product A
Product B
Product C
```

and would like to convert it into categorical variable where I have used the following coding:

```
plancat <- factor(Product,levels=c(1,2,3),labels = c("Product A","Product B","Product C"))
```

However, it did not work. Can someone help me why this has happened please?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate "how it didn't work"?

Comment: I have 'attach(data)' and the following error is being prompted as well now: 'The following objects are masked from prepaid (pos = 3)'

Comment: That is a warning not an error. Just a tip: You should rename your dataset something except  `data`.

Comment: @NelsonGon - ok but what is the warning?

Comment: The warning is just telling you that the object is found in two places. I cannot be sure but it's normally safe to ignore. Might lead to some problems especially when you use the wrong object because it has been masked.

Comment: You can try this although it may be tedious: `df$Product<-as.factor(df$Product)
levels(df$Product)<-c(1,2,3)
forcats::fct_recode(df$Product,"Product A"="1","Product B"="2","Product C"="3")`

Answer (score 1):

In the OP it mentions "multiple columns". Here's some data based on the OP, but with two columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
Product1 <- c("Product A","Product B","Product C","Product A")
Product2 <- c("Product A","Product B","Product C","Product A")
df <- tibble(Product1, Product2)
```

The two columns are `character` class. Using `mutate_at` from `dplyr` / `tidyverse` you can specify the columns to convert class to anything you want - in this case `factor`. You can also pass a vector of column names instead of calling out the columns individually.

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(c("Product1", "Product2"), list(~ factor(.)))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Product1  Product2 
  <fct>     <fct>    
1 Product A Product A
2 Product B Product B
3 Product C Product C
4 Product A Product A
```

Answer (score 0):

Factor levels and labels have to match. You can convert a factor to numeric easily :

```
Product <- c("Product A","Product B","Product C","Product A")
plancat <- factor(Product)
plancat
#[1] Product A Product B Product C Product A
#Levels: Product A Product B Product C
as.numeric(plancat)
#[1] 1 2 3 1
```

Comment: Why convert it to numeric? The goal is to change levels not data type.

Comment: @Clemsang - this is for all the rows right? I have around 512K rows so thats why I would require an automated one

Comment: @NelsonGon I am used to convert to numeric when I want to use statistical models that require numeric input. It might not be exactly expected output thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi this is for a full vector here, same as a full column like `dataframe_name$column_name` which is a full row. The correspondance between numeric and text is `levels(plancat)` here.